# any shortcut to get set<String> from map<Id,Set<String>> ?

Tags: apex, list, map, set, collection

```
 Map<String,Set<String>> st= new Map<String,Set<String>>();
st.put('one',new Set<String>{'1','2'});
 Set<string> ss = new Set<String>();
 ss.addAll(st.values());//Error. I think we should iterate and add to set one by on. any Idea to get all at once (like any addAll..)
system.debug(ss);
```

any shortcut to get set from map> ? But it return

```
list<set<string>>()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to loop through and use `addAll`. There is no shortcut.

```
Set<String> allValues = new Set<String>();
for (Set<String> subset : st.values())
{
    allValues.addAll(subset);
}
```